# Unable to see code coverage tab on sonar dashboard for selected applications

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have couple of unit testcases written in my project. On the sonar dashboard the code coverage tab is completely missing. 
For some other projects the sonar dashboard is showing expected code coverage though.

the pom file of project is as attached :

```
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

How can it be enabled ?

Adding logs for the error related to used java version but unable to identify the root cause for the same. As provided the pom.xml is using java 11 for compiler source and compiler target.

Adding logs where error is being logged due to java versioning :

```
 Unable to create symbol table for : /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_checkingBuild/src/main/java/com/test/test2/MyServices/config/AppConfig.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:242)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:109)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:116)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:110)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:302)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:297)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:271)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Adding logs for reference. Getting this warning for every java class :

```
[WARNING] Exception during analysis of file /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_checkingMyservices/target/classes/com/test/test2/myservices/repository/ImageUrl.class
java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_checkingMyservices/target/classes/com/test/test2/myservices/repository/ImageUrl.class.
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:166)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:138)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:161)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeClassFile(JacocoReportReader.java:153)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeFiles(JacocoReportReader.java:116)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.readExecutionData(UnitTestAnalyzer.java:126)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.analyse(UnitTestAnalyzer.java:95)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.execute(JaCoCoSensor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:302)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:297)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:271)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:117)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:136)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

The build is still getting successfully created. 
Also, from the logs it is quite clear that java version is the issue. but unable to identify, what is causing the issue.

Comment: There is no option to turn on/off the coverage info. You need to investigate your build pipeline and all the log files (including the SonarQube once). Sonarqube is depending on the converage information you provided.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Please see the logs added. Can you point out the problem ? In the sense that can it be a problem of the pom.xml used.  or it is a problem specific to sonarqube server.  I found this issue others have observed that is related to version of SonarJava plugin used by SonarQube server . https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unsupported-class-file-major-version-55-when-executing-sonar-maven-plugin-under-openjdk11/3507.  Could it be related to this ?

Comment: Based on the information provided you could have the same issue. Based on [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/releases) page the newest release is 6.0 and it is just released. Do you use an SonarQube LTS version and did you update all plugins you use (login as admin)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Unsupported class file major version 55
```

Suggests there is something wrong with java version used to build/run/test code.

I think you may be using outdated `jacoco-maven-plugin`, according to this page -> https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html official java 11 support started with version `0.8.3`.

Comment: Using 0.8.3 didn't do much. It is still not showing coverage

Comment: Hmm... I recall we also had an issue with sonar java plugin. Have you checked that part? Have you checked if jacoco report is created?

Comment: I can see jacoco.exe being created with the build. I also tested the same by deploying sonar qube community edition on my local and ran the mvn sonar:sonar goal for the projet in hand. I can see the coverage there. Its this particular remote sonarqube server where I am getting all these issues. Can I conclude that this issue is not related to any plugin used in pom?

Comment: It does look like server side issue. Most likely java plugin is outdated.